# Simple Linear Regression with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, linear-regression

Im working with Quantrix. A java based software.

The scripting language is Groovy and i want to build a customized function, a simple linear regression.

Im not a java developer so i really only know the basics.

My code looks at the moment like this. I think the problem is somewhere in the syntax, which im not that familiar working with.

```
double simple_regression(double dependend_values, double independend_values, double x_test)
{

    slope = double slope(dependend_values, independend_values)
    intercept = double intercept(dependend_values, independend_values)
    
    return intercept + slope * x_test

}
```

Another try was to write it like that:

```
double SimpleRegression(double dependend_values, double independend_values, double x_test)

{

regression = new SimpleRegression();
regression.addData(dependend_values, independend_values);

return regression.predict(x_test)

}
```

Here is another try, done in a java online compiler.

```
public class simple_regression {
    static void main (String [] args) {
      int x=10;
      int y=25;
      int x_test=20;
      double predict;
      SimpleRegression sreg = SimpleRegression();
      sreg.addData();
      sreg.addData(x, y);
      predict = sreg.predict(x_test);

      System.out.println(predict);
    }
}
```

and this is the error i get.

```
/simple_regression.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
      SimpleRegression sreg = SimpleRegression();
      ^
  symbol:   class SimpleRegression
  location: class simple_regression
/simple_regression.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
      SimpleRegression sreg = SimpleRegression();
                              ^
  symbol:   method SimpleRegression()
  location: class simple_regression
2 errors
```

Comment: what is your question/issue?

Comment: Its not working. So i think i did a mistake with the syntax which i cant see, because im not an experienced java developer. Maybe someone can tell me what the correct syntax would be when creating a simple linear regression in java/groovy?

Comment: how do you know `it's not working`? do you have any error? if no - how you are running your code?

Comment: I don't think `slope = double slope(dependend_values, independend_values)` or `intercept = double intercept(dependend_values, independend_values)` are valid Groovy statements.

Comment: @daggett only functions that work i can safe in Quantrix. And these ones cant be safed. I tried now another version in a java online compiler. I edited my post, so you can see the error message i get.

Comment: `SimpleRegression()` - do you mean this one: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html